# Encapsulates runtime exceptions on a retun method, or generate a exception method?

Tags: java, exception, methods, return

I want to know if it's a good practice encapsulate a throw in a method and call it in a return method

```
int returnMethod(){
  if(ok){
    return 1;
  }     
  alwaysReturnRuntimeException();
  return 1; //Fake
}

void alwaysReturnRuntimeException(){
  if(specificError){
    throw new OneRuntimeException();
  }
  // General error
  throw new GeneralRuntimeException();
}
```

Or it's better generate the exception, but don't throw. Only return it and throw it on parent method.

```
int returnMethod(){
  if(ok){
    return 1;
  }     
  throw buildException();
}

void buildException(){
  if(specificError){
    return new OneRuntimeException();
  }
  // General error
  return GeneralRuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: This is probably opinion-based. And my opinion is that calling a method to throw an exception is closer to obfuscation than to encapsulation. Rather convert that method into an exception factory and let callers have an explicit `throw` statement.

Comment: +1 to obfuscation. I've just reformulate the question to avoid based opinions. The factory method it's a good option, but, too effort for 2 kinds of exceptions that this method gonna handled.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a method that decides which kind of exception has to be thrown is a valid approach to reuse code, but only if it really fits your application design (without knowing more details about the rest of the code, I can't give a well-founded alternative). However, I strongly advise against unchecked exceptions in your code (but that's another story, and kind of subjective).

Two recommendations in case you really need this approach:

- Name unambiguously your throwing method showing its direct intention, something like `throwMyException()`  (`alwaysReturnRuntimeException()` is a bad name for a method that returns nothing)
- Even though it is not required by the compiler in the case of unchecked exceptions, declare the throwable exceptions in the method signature, in order to avoid obfuscation.

Your code might be like this:

```java
int returnMethod(){
  if(!ok){
    throwRuntimeException();
  }     
  return 1;
}

void throwRuntimeException() throws OneRuntimeException, GeneralRuntimeException {
  if(specificError){
    throw new OneRuntimeException();
  }
  // General error
  throw new GeneralRuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis Iñesta . You are right on naming method. My bad at this point. On battle of uncheked exceptions, like runtime, in this case is a requirement of app desing.

I've just reformulate the question.